# type casting issue with int in java

Tags: java

Trying to pass a java test I faced the following question

```
class A {
    int f() { return 1; }
}
class B extends A {
    int f() { return 2; }
}
class C extends B {
    int f() { return 3; }
    int test() { 
        return super.f() +
               ((A)this).f();
    }
}
```

Can't figure out why `((A)this).f()` returns 3 but not 1?

Comment: That is how polymorphism works. It invokes method based on instance type, not reference type.

Answer (score 3):

This is [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch), the *static type* of the object (`(A)this`, which is `A`) does not matter, only the *dynamic type*, and that is `C`.

Similarly, if you do

```
A a = this;
a.f();
```

The same value (3) will be returned.